# PHP: Print post value after insert in DataBase

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to insert data using in table users.

After insert i go to in the same page with

```
  $url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header('Location: '.$url."&sent=yes");
```

So the page was refresh,I need to print PDF in order to print a file for that user. I want to send to Print.php name and `social_security_number` using POST. I am able to do this using GET in Print.php like this:

```
$insertGoTo = "Print.php?ssn=".$_POST['social_security_number'];
```

and in Print.php

```
$find_ssn = $_POST[ssn];
```

But the $_POST[ssn] was empty, What can i do `$_POST[ssn]` in the same value

my code :-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// sql insert to DB
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `olmaa` ( `aid` , `firstname` , `fathername` , `familyname` , `bday` , `bmonth` , `byear` , `bpcity` , `bpstate` , `bpcountry` , `nationalty` , `placenow` , `jobs` , `degree` , `degreespical` , `enjazat` , `moalef` , `moassa` , `nameofjeha` , `namemasol` ,`tell` , `fax` , `email` ,`maswgha`,`cv`,`work`,`date` )
VALUES ( '".$aid."', '".$firstname."',  '".$fathername."',  '".$familyname."',  '".$bday."',  '".$bmonth."',  '".$byear."',  '".$bpcity."',  '".$bpstate."',  '".$bpcountry."',  '".$nationalty."',  '".$placenow."',  '".$jobs."',  '".$degree."',  '".$degreespical."',  '".$enjazat."',  '".$moalef."',  '".$moassa."',  '".$nameofjeha."', '".$namemasol."', '".$tell."',  '".$fax."',  '".$email."',  '".$maswgha."' ,  '".$filenameword."' ,  '".$filenamezip."' , '".time()."') "); 

$url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header('Location: '.$url."&sent=yes");
}

if(isset($_GET['sent']) && $_GET['sent']== 'yes'){ 
?>
<form name="pt_list" action="classes/aplay_pdf.php" method="post"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="pdf"  value="PDF">
</form>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: SSN is highly sensitive data and should not be passed around so carelessly.  Never put this type of data in the Query String.

Comment: And where are you using $_GET['ssn'] now? I just see a form and a mysql query here. Aswell I see no reference to the file "Print.php" here.

Comment: this my question, how can send the same data to another page to print it after insert to Data Base

Comment: header('Location:www.whatever.de/print.php?ssn=somevalue');

Comment: but i need send by button submit not by header, i send it it after insert to data base and refresh page

Comment: Then use button.submit (=Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the quotes around `$_POST[ssn]`;
Aswell - from what I see here, your refering to a `GET` variable, and not `POST`. 
`GET Variable = URL | POST Variable = Background`

Your code has to look like this:

```
$insertGoTo = "Print.php?ssn=".$_POST['social_security_number'];
$find_ssn = $_GET['ssn'];
```

Comment: mm ,i try `_GET['ssn'];` but the value empty , i think the value empty because refresh page , what can i do

Comment: @Kam check the URL, does it say print.php?ssn=someValue ?

Comment: first `container.php?fun=olmaa` then if submit we show this link `container.php?fun=olmaa&sent=yes` then if `$_GET['sent']== 'yes'` we show PDF print, when click to it we must print it

Comment: Well, theres no GET Variable called 'ssn' in your URL. So $_GET['ssn'] is empty. Your error has to be somewhere else - but I dont see your other code..

Comment: Aswell you should not just use $_GET and $_POST. You should make sure theres no bad input comming by validating it before usage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure errors regarding a constant is not being thrown? if not. Turn on error reporting, you are missing quotes inside your $_POST array:

```
$find_ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
```

---

Also. You should not be using `$_POST` as you're looking for a $_GET value due to data being appended to the URL:

```
$find_ssn = $_GET['ssn'];
```